# Sinatra to-do list tutorial problems

Tags: ruby, sinatra

So, I'm new to Ruby/Sinatra, did a bunch of codecademy lessons and the like. I decided until I actually built something, I wouldn't really understand some core concepts.

I found a [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/singing-with-sinatra-the-recall-app-2/) for building a to-do list app in Sinatra, and all was fine and good until I got to the edit and delete functionality. I can read and write to/from the database, but whenever I try to edit or delete, it skips straight to "Note not found".

I couldn't figure this out myself, so I asked a developer friend of mine. When I sent him the code, everything worked absolutely fine for him! We tried a couple of different possible fixes, but to no end. I even downloaded the code from the guy's [github](https://github.com/danharper/Singing-with-Sinatra/tree/master/Track%202%20-%20The%20Good%20Life%20%28The%20Recall%20App%29), just in case there was a random mistake somewhere in my own code, to no avail.

So, I come here asking for some help! Why won't this work!

Clarification: Here's some of the code, where I think the problem may lie. In edit.erb and delete.erb, no matter what it is going to the else statement and sending me to "note not found". It's reading properly from the database, as my homepage can add and show notes.

recall.rb

```
get '/:id' do
    @note = Note.get params[:id]
    @title = "Edit note ##{params[:id]}"
    erb :edit
end

put '/:id' do
    n = Note.get params[:id]
n.content = params[:content]
n.complete = params[:complete] ? 1 : 0
n.updated_at = Time.now
n.save
redirect '/'
end

get '/:id/delete' do
    @note = Note.get params[:id]
    @title = "Confirm deletion of note ##{params[:id]}"
    erb :delete
end

delete '/:id' do
    n = Note.get params[:id]
    n.destroy!
    redirect '/'
end
```

edit.erb

```
<% if @note %>
  <form action="/<%= @note.id %>" method="post" id="edit">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    <textarea name="content"><%= @note.content %></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="complete" <%= "checked" if @note.complete %>>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <p><a href="/<%= @note.id %>/delete">Delete</a></p>
<% else %>
  <p>Note not found.</p>
<% end %>
```

delete.erb

```
<% if @note %>
  <p>Are you sure you want to delete the following note: <em>"<%= @note.content %>"</em>?</p>
  <form action="/<%= @note.id %>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Yes, Delete It!">
    <a href="/<%= @note.id %>">Cancel</a>
  </form>
<% else %>
  <p>Note not found.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unless you post us a short, working example that demonstrates your issue, you're effectively asking us 'What have I got in my pockets?'

Comment: edited for some clarification, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moving the delete-route above the other routes seemed to work for me, which would suggest that the `/:id` -part in the route definition catches the `/delete`-part as well. You can see the generated regexps with `Sinatra::Application.routes`.

Here's a minimal:

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'dm-core'
require 'dm-migrations'
require 'dm-sweatshop'

# Models
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite::memory:')

class Note
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :content, Text, :required => true
  property :complete, Boolean, :default => false
  property :created_at, DateTime, :default => lambda {Time.now}
  property :updated_at, DateTime

  before(:save) { attribute_set(:updated_at, Time.now) }
end

DataMapper.finalize.auto_migrate!

# Fixtures
Note.fix {{
  :content => /\w+/.gen
}}

100.of { Note.gen }

# Routes
before("/:id") {|id| @note = Note.get id }

get("/:id/delete") {|id| @note = Note.get id; erb :delete }

get("/:id") { erb :edit }

put "/:id" do
  @note.attributes = params["note"]
  @note.save ? redirect(to("/")) : erb(:edit)
end

delete("/:id") { @note.destroy; redirect(to("/")) }

# Templates
template :layout do
  '<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body><%= yield %></body>
  </html>'
end

template :edit do
  '<% if @note %>
    <form action="/<%= @note.id %>" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
      <textarea name="note[content]"><%= @note.content %></textarea>
      <input type="checkbox" name="note[complete]"
        <%= @note.complete? && "checked" %> >
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <p><a href="/<%= @note.id %>/delete">Delete</a></p>
  <% else %>
    <p>Note not found.</p>
  <% end %>'
end

template :delete do
  '<% if @note %>
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete the following note:
      <em>"<%= @note.content %>"</em>?</p>
    <form action="/<%= @note.id %>" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
      <input type="submit" value="Yes, Delete it!">
      <a href="/<%= @note.id %>">Cancel</a>
    </form>
  <% else %>
    <p>Note not found</p>
  <% end %>'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still interesting someone, but a simple

```
params[:id].to_i
```

fixed it for me.